# gstreamer error : MP4 files and thumbnails doesn't work

Tags: nautilus, video, codecs, gstreamer

I think I have done something, but I can't tell what exactly... Now, my Ubuntu doesn't want to decode MPEG-4 and H.264 video-files (files extensions `.avi` `.mp4`).

`vlc` still works (of course, it has built-in codecs) but `totem` and the thumbnailer stopped working.

Here's what I did recently that might be related :

```
sudo apt-get install libvo-aacenc-dev libx264-dev libtheora-dev librtmp-dev libvorbis-dev libfdk-aac-dev libmp3lame-dev libfaac-dev libpulse-dev libxvidcore-dev
```

I used them to build `libav-tools`from GIT. Now `libav`works like a charm, and that makes me think that my `libx264` is fine (which is, I think, used to decode H.264 and MPEG-4).

---

I have this error message :

```
$ ▶ totem video.mp4
** Message: Missing plugin: gstreamer|1.0|totem|H.264 decoder|decoder-video/x-h264, stream-format=(string)avc, alignment=(string)au, level=(string)3.2, profile=(string)main, parsed=(boolean)true (H.264 decoder)
```

---

I also tried [this](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=1502057&p=9418724#post9418724) and I have [plenty of `gstreamer-*`](http://paste.ubuntu.com/7068398/) package installed.

Can you help me ?

Comment: Could you please start totem from the command line and attach possible error messages?

Comment: @spineau : done.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to install gstreamer1.0-libav:

```
sudo apt-get install gstreamer1.0-libav
```

---

Check if libthumbnailer0 is properly installed as well:

```
sudo apt-get install libthumbnailer0
```

Then, remove the thumbnails cache :

```
sudo rm -r ~/.cache/thumbnails
```

And finally restart Nautilus :

```
nautilus -q
```

Comment: Yep, I figured that out myself thanks to your idea of checking the error-message, but it works only for `totem` and not the thumbnailer... any ideas?

Comment: even after rebooting your system?

Comment: yep, but I found the problem, I edited your answer. Now everything works, thanks for your help !